# a retractable JTextArea with scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Goodevening

how can have a JTextArea like in netbeans (see the pic)

[image]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img10.hostingpics.net/pics/968190Sans_titre.png))</sub>

my code of the JTextArea:

```
   JTextArea  infoArea = new JTextArea(10,10);
   infoArea.setLineWrap(true);
   infoArea.setFont(police);
   infoArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
   infoArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   infoArea.setEditable(false);

   JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(infoArea);
   scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
   scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 10, 0));
   scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sousFrame.getWidth(),90));
   scroll.setFont( new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13));
   scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Output"));
```

thank you

Comment: Could you please try to explain what exactly does not work?

Comment: @Peter Lang: it works well but i juste want to make it dockaable or retractable like the output panel in netbeans  ( see the picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what NetBeans uses, but we used [flexdock](https://flexdock.dev.java.net/) at my last company to create dockable windows in a Java Swing application (assuming this is what you meant by "retractable").

Comment: @tuxou: Okay, then a docking framework is what you need.  Flexdock is just one of many that you can find online (many of them for free).